# C Linked List valgrind Invalid Read of Size

Tags: c, linked-list, malloc, valgrind, free

I have a problem with my Linked List and the valgrind output. 
Without further adieu here is my linked list:

```
typedef struct Map map;

struct Map
{
    void *address;
    double free_time;
    map* next;
}*map_list;
```

The list is created using a dummy head node. As you can see, the struct holds an address and a free time, which I try to associate them.

In the `find_and_free` function I search this list using a time and if this time is smaller than the one stored in the list, I deallocate the saved address. And then I deallocate the list node as well.

This is the function used to find any free time that is smaller than the one I am passing. If it is smaller, I free the address stored to the list, and then call the `delete_map_node` function to also deallocate the node of the list.

```
void find_and_free_address(map *root, double mtime)
{
    map *current = root->next;
    assert(current);
    while(current)
    {
        if(current->free_time < mtime)
        {

            printf("there is something to FREE now\n");
            printf("the time to check for free is %lf and the maps free time is %lf\n", mtime,current->free_time);
            printf("The map contains an address that is time to free\n");
            //free_allocated_address(&current->address);
            free(current->address);
            delete_map_node(map_list, current->free_time);
            //delete(map_list,current->free_time);
            //return next;
        }

        else
        {
            printf("there is nothing to free now\n");
        }

        current = current->next; //FIRST ERROR
    }
    printf("THE MAP SIZE AFTER REMOVALS IS %d\n", map_size(map_list));
}
```

And this is the `delete_map_node` function

```
map* delete_map_node(map *root,double ftime)
{
    if (root==NULL)
    {
        return NULL;
    }

    //map *temporary;

    if (root->free_time == ftime)
    {
        map *temporary = root->next;
        free(root); //SECOND ERROR
        root = temporary;
        return temporary;
    }

    root->next = delete_map_node(root->next, ftime);
    //free(root->address);
    return root;
}
```

I am aware that those two can be combined to only one function.

valgrind, reports no memory leaks or uninitialized values. However when I execute the following command:

```
valgrind --tool=memcheck --leak-check=full --track-origins=yes -v ./a.out
```

I get the following output :

```
==6807== Invalid read of size 4
==6807==    at 0x8049228: find_and_free_address (Map.c:123)
==6807==    by 0x8048DA6: second_iteration (List.c:150)
==6807==    by 0x8048C6B: first_iteration (List.c:113)
==6807==    by 0x8048908: main (Fscanf.c:63)
==6807==  Address 0x42005bc is 12 bytes inside a block of size 16 free'd
==6807==    at 0x402AF3D: free (vg_replace_malloc.c:468)
==6807==    by 0x804929F: delete_map_node (Map.c:142)
==6807==    by 0x80492C1: delete_map_node (Map.c:147)
==6807==    by 0x8049216: find_and_free_address (Map.c:113)
==6807==    by 0x8048DA6: second_iteration (List.c:150)
==6807==    by 0x8048C6B: first_iteration (List.c:113)
==6807==    by 0x8048908: main (Fscanf.c:63)
```

I can see that the error is that I access `root->next` and `current->next` after I have freed them, but I have not managed to do without it.

Can you suggest me a way, to get rid of this error?

Comment: What is `map_list` in `delete_map_node(map_list, ...)`? Is it global?!

Comment: map_list is the name of the List I am using. You can see it in the definition of the structure.

Comment: Ah yes. So it _is_ global. Since you are doing the excellent job of passing `root` and returning it from your functions (well, the returning is missing from `find_and_free_address`), why not remove the global variable? You can then define as many lists as you want without problems.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One problem that I see is that in `delete_map_node` you free `root` (which might be `map_list` passed from `find_and_free_address`), but you don't actually change `map_list` which means that when `delete_map_node` returns the `map_list` variable points to unallocated memory. Accessing `map_list` afterwards leads to [*undefined behavior*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior).

The simple solution to this is to assign the return value of `delete_map_node` to `map_list`:

```
map_list = delete_map_node(map_list, current->free_time);
```

Also, what happens when `delete_map_node` frees the node in the list that is `current` in the `find_and_free_address` function? Then `current = current->next` will also lead to undefined behavior.

Comment: I followed your advice, but still I get the same output from Valgrind.Invalid read of size 4 in the current = current->next; and is 12 bytes inside a block of size 16 free'd in the free(root);

Comment: @dimitrios, regarding the `current = current->next` output, simply keep a `next = current->next` on top of the while loop, and on the bottom do `current = next`. This way, you keep the next pointer before possibly deleting current.

Comment: Actually, that solved the reported error. Thanks to both of you.